# how to configure the configMapAndSecretChangeDetectionStrategy because every deploy i have some configmap that changes and need to detect that

Tags: kubernetes, deployment, devops

i have a change that is done every time that my app deploys on some global configmap
and i have some pods that need to detect that automatically instead to redeploy the some pods every time.

i see some thing called configMapAndSecretChangeDetectionStrategy in kubernetes documentation https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/config-api/kubelet-config.v1beta1/#kubelet-config-k8s-io-v1beta1-ResourceChangeDetectionStrategy but it was not clear for me

Answer (score 0):

> When a ConfigMap currently consumed in a volume is updated, projected keys are eventually updated as well. The kubelet checks whether the mounted ConfigMap is fresh on every periodic sync. However, the kubelet uses its local cache for getting the current value of the ConfigMap. The type of the cache is configurable using the *ConfigMapAndSecretChangeDetectionStrategy* field in the KubeletConfiguration struct. A ConfigMap can be either propagated by watch (default), ttl-based, or by redirecting all requests directly to the API server. As a result, the total delay from the moment when the ConfigMap is updated to the moment when new keys are projected to the Pod can be as long as the kubelet sync period + cache propagation delay, where the cache propagation delay depends on the chosen cache type (it equals to watch propagation delay, ttl of cache, or zero correspondingly).

> ConfigMaps consumed as environment variables are not updated automatically and require a pod restart.

> Note: A container using a ConfigMap as a subPath volume mount will not receive ConfigMap updates.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/configmap/#mounted-configmaps-are-updated-automatically

In summary, if you update the configMap which is mounted as a Volume, the Pods will receive the change and restart automatically.

If you don't want to suffer this effect, create configMap with randomly generated suffix and change the name of the cM in the Deployment mount from time to time.